# What was the name of the Mac (68000) assembler?

Tags: macos, assembly, 68000

I'm sure there were several, but the one I was thinking of would display a nice text screen when you crashed the computer thoroughly.

The Text was "Well smoke me a kipper."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the assembler was Fantasm.

Comment: Wow nice find.  So Lightsoft out of the UK was the developer and it looks like they are now gone unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

No one else has answered this, so I'll answer the part I can: the original Macintosh debugger was [MacsBug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacsBug).

So far as the kipper quote goes, the only thing that comes to mind is the  **[Pathogen](http://virus.wikidot.com/pathogen)**  computer virus.

Comment: "Smoke me a kipper. I'll be back for breakfast." is from [Red Dwarf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Dwarf).

Comment: There was also microbug (which lived on the ROM) for those who hadn't installed MacsBug. Very primitive indeed.

Answer (score 2):

There was another 68000 Macintosh debugger called TMON.  I don't remember the kipper quote being in it, but it's been a while.